# KOMA-script custom float placement incorrect

Tags: floats, koma-script

I'm exploring KOMA and am trying to create a new type of float using the built-in `\DeclareNewTOC` functionality. However, the float seems to be pushed to its own page (and/or before any other floats of the same floattype). Tables and figures seem fine, however

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
    type=example,
    types=examples,
    float,
    floatpos=tb,
    name=Example,
    listname={List of Examples}
]{loe}
\setuptoc{loe}{chapteratlist}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\lipsum[1-6]

\begin{example}
\caption{Example caption}
This is an example
\end{example}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The result is the example is pushed to the third page, even though there is plenty of room on page 2. Thoughts?

Example output:

[image: (image of example output)]

Comment: odd, it isn't picking up the default. if you use `\begin{example}[tb]` then it works.

Comment: Seems to be a bug. You should write a bug report.

Comment: Ok reported to the email from the scrguien document. I will post a follow-up if I hear anything

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in v3.12 (2013/12/19) of KOMA-Script. If you haven't already done so you may consider updating your TeX distribution.

Comment: Thanks! I sent an email to the address listed in the Koma script documentation, but the email bounced back.

Comment: @BenP. The easiest way is to write Markus Kohm directly to the address found on www.komascript.de or leave a post there in the forum.